# How to run 2 TPS load with multiple https request randomly on a single thread group?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have to run 2 TPS load with multiple request on a single Threadgroup, Below are my settings :

- One Tread group named A
- 7 https request under A

How i can achieve 2TPS load ?
What will be the Ramp-up Period and No of Treads to run 2 TPS load with 7 request?
How the requests will go in non-sequential manner/ Randomly ?

Tried with Test Fragment and constant throughput timer but not getting accurate results

Answer (score 0):

There are following options available:

1. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer), 2 TPS will be 120 requests per minute.

   [image]
2. Precise Throughput Timer, in this case you will need to set/calculate your desired test duration, here is an example setup for 1 minute test duration:

   [image]
3. And probably the easiest way is [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin), it provides easy visual way of defining the load

   [image]

Also be aware that the timers can only **pause** JMeter to **limit** the TPS to the desired value so you have to supply sufficient amount of threads and the exact value depends on your application response time. Also it's possible to connect the Throughput Shaping Timer to [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/), this way JMeter will be able to kick off extra threads if current amount is not enough for conducting the necessary load.

Comment: Used Constant_Throughput_Timer and not getting accurate result, 
1. Now getting approximate 3 TPS load not getting 2 TPS
2. Only for Request 1 ,I am getting successful results not for others
Queries:
1. What will be the Ramp-up Period and No of Treads to run 2 TPS load with 7 request ?
2. Now the requests are going continuously what will be the setting to run the load for 1 min , 10 min etc